# c++ - Numbers of iterations before int_max was reached

Tags: c++

Below is a code which checks if a given number is a Lychrel number. What this basically means is that this program takes the sum of a number and its reverse, and then take the sum of *that* number and its reverse, etc. until it finds a palindrome. If it doesn't find such a number within a certain amount of iterations (I have chosen 50 in this program), we conclude it's a Lychrel number.

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int rev(int number){ //function to reverse numbers
    int rem = 0;
    while (number > 0){
       rem = (rem * 10) + (number % 10);
        number = number / 10; 
    }
return rem;
}

bool Palindromecheck(int num){ //bool to check if a number is palindrome 
    return (num == rev(num));
}

bool isLychrel(int checknumber, int &iterationcount){
    const int iterCount = 50;
    int reversed = rev(checknumber);
    int counter = 0;
        if (checknumber == reversed){ //makes sure that a number that starts out as a palindrome gets value "0" for iterations
            return false;
        }
    while (counter < iterCount){ //loop that keeps going until it finds a palindrome or reaches 50 iterations 
        counter = (counter + 1);
        iterationcount = counter;
        if (Palindromecheck(reversed + checknumber))
            return false;
        checknumber = checknumber + reversed;
        reversed = rev(checknumber);
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int checknumber;
    int iterationcount;
    cout << "Please enter a number: \n";
    cin >> checknumber;
    bool lychrelcheck = isLychrel(checknumber, iterationcount);
    if (lychrelcheck == true){
        cout << checknumber << " is a Lychrel number. \n";
    }
    else
        cout << checknumber << " is not a Lychrel number. \n";
        cout << iterationcount << " is the numbers of iterations necessary to reach a palindrome. \n";
    return 0;

}
```

Now, this program works fine from what I've seen, but it has two faults which I don't know how to solve:

1. If you give the program a number of 1 digit, it gives you a very large (sometimes negative) amount of iterations. I don't even know why this should be possible since the maximum amount of iterations is 50. On top of that, it gives you a different number of iterations for the same number. For example, checknumber = 5 could give you a huge positive number of iterations or a huge negative number of iterations. I tried to change it by taking a line from the code and slightly modifying it:

   ```
   bool isLychrel(int checknumber, int &iterationcount){
      const int iterCount = 50;
      int reversed = rev(checknumber);
      int counter = 0;
          if ((checknumber == reversed) or (checknumber <= 9)){ 
      }
   ```

I thought this would assign an iteration count of 0 to numbers below 10, but it doesn't, the same problem persists for some reason.

2. This program can't handle to complete all 50 iterations, because the numbers get too large (I don't mind, I purposely chose 50 for that). I want to be able to display after how many iterations int_max is reached for a certain number. Right now, it simply says it completed 50 iterations every time int_max is exceeded, even if it's not true that a number is a Lychrel number and it didn't even complete 50 iterations (or it did, but perhaps with negative numbers and such).

I've read somewhere that you can do that with include , but I don't know how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, if you input 1 digit number, your function returns before `iterationcount` get any value. To fix it, set `iterationcount` to 0 in the beginning of your function:

```
int counter = 0;
iterationcount = counter;
```

Actually you may use `iterationcount` as counter and not create a separate variable for it.

For second problem use `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`. So new function would look like that:

```
bool isLychrel(int checknumber, int &iterationcount) {
    const int iterCount = 50;
    int reversed = rev(checknumber);
    int counter = 0;
    iterationcount = counter;
    if (checknumber == reversed) { //makes sure that a number that starts out as a palindrome gets value "0" for iterations
        return false;
    }
    while (counter < iterCount) { //loop that keeps going until it finds a palindrome or reaches 50 iterations
        if (std::numeric_limits<int>::max() - reversed < checknumber)
            return true;
        ++counter;
        iterationcount = counter;
        if (Palindromecheck(reversed + checknumber))
            return false;
        checknumber += reversed;
        reversed = rev(checknumber);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I tried doing your solution for the first part, the problem persists, it doesn't seem to have been solved. As for the second part, implementing your code  doesn't work as it now says that numbers such as "89" and "196" are lychrel numbers (which is good), but it took 0 iterations, which is wrong

Comment: @user29855 sorry for typo, `<` instead of `>`. I fixed it, try new code. About first one, when I write 8, it gives me 0 iteration. What's your output?

Comment: Ah yes, I just figured that out, as for the second part, it works now, it was my own mistake. Thanks for the answer, I was unaware of the existence of std::numeric_limits<int>::max().